# Camel-activemq component inside of karaf

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-karaf

Karaf 4.4.3, camel 3.20.5
I have a blueprint with

```xml
    <bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.camel.component.activemq.ActiveMQComponent">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
        <property name="username" value="karaf" />
        <property name="password" value="karaf" />
    </bean>
```

I get error when I try to start my app inside of karaf:

```
org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Error when instantiating bean activemq of class org.apache.camel.component.activemq.ActiveMQComponent
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/JMSContext
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.JMSContext not found by org.apache.geronimo.specs.geronimo-jms_1.1_spec [203]
```

My features:

```xml
        <feature>transaction</feature>
        <feature>jndi</feature>
        <feature>pax-jdbc-config</feature>
        <feature>pax-jdbc-postgresql</feature>
        <feature>pax-jdbc-pool-dbcp2</feature>
        <feature>jdbc</feature>
        <feature>jms</feature>
        <feature>activemq-client</feature>
        <feature>pax-jdbc</feature>
        <feature dependency="true">aries-blueprint</feature>
        <feature>cxf</feature>
        <feature>camel-activemq</feature>
```

I've also tried initializing ActiveMQConnectionFactory but was getting same NoClassDeffound error.
Also tried installing `bundle:install mvn:javax.jms/javax.jms-api/2.0.1`, but that didn't help.

I'm guessing there is some API mismatch or I'm missing a dependency.

*Without the ActiveMQComponent the bundle was working fine.*

The activemq broker is inside the same karaf instance, I'm connecting to it via hawtio with no issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That component is wired to JMS 2.0 API jar. You need to change your feature to install a javax.jms-api jar that is 2.0 and *not* the geronimo-jms-api jar that supports JMS v1.1